# Complex ORDER BY two alternate columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need order a list of access from the newest to the latest, it can be done using the table primary key Id. But now I want to group the access to the same document defined by the second key.

So if a have this result:

- 199985 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Sol Supuestos 254 y 255 Parte...
- 199984 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Jurisdiccion Voluntaria (20-...
- 199983 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Sol Supuestos 254 y 255 Parte...
- 198911 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Repaso Contencioso Administra...
- 198910 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Repaso Contencioso Administra...

I need show in this order:

- 199985 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Sol Supuestos 254 y 255 Parte...
- 199983 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Sol Supuestos 254 y 255 Parte...
- 199984 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Jurisdiccion Voluntaria (20-...
- 198911 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Repaso Contencioso Administra...
- 198910 Clase Just Vet+Marzo Repaso Contencioso Administra...

I need order by main ID and then group by the document name...

Thank you all

Comment: Can you provide sql and sample table you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question; but it lacks an example table or code so I'll assume your table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(199985, 'Clase Just Vet+Marzo Sol Supuestos 254 y 255 Parte...'),
(199984, 'Clase Just Vet+Marzo Jurisdiccion Voluntaria (20-...'),
(199983, 'Clase Just Vet+Marzo Sol Supuestos 254 y 255 Parte...'),
(198911, 'Clase Just Vet+Marzo Repaso Contencioso Administra...'),
(198910, 'Clase Just Vet+Marzo Repaso Contencioso Administra...');
```

I found the requested order a bit tricky so I thought first we need to get the ids sorted & grouped then use it as a subquery which is as follows:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids FROM `test` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

which give the result:

```
ids 
199985,199983   
199984  
198911,198910
```

As your might know you cannot use a subquery that return more than 1 row to do anything useful, so I needed to combine the results using another `group_concat`
to accomplish this we need to add another column to force mysql to use it in a group by since there's no similarity in the above result we can group by.

resulting query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`ids`) FROM( 
          SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids, 'x' as `useful_column` 
          FROM `test` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `id` DESC) `table`
```

As expected this works well, and we get a combine result of ids as follows:

```
199985,199983,199984,198911,198910
```

which is the sort order mentioned in your question; now to actually get the sorted result you want you just have to combine this result with a select as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`id`, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`ids`) FROM( 
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids, 'x' as `useful_column` FROM `test` 
 GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `id` DESC) `table`));
```

**Keep in mind** that I only went through this question because I found it interesting & wanted to try to solve it so this solution might not be the best one available as there is a limit to group_concat & I am not actually sure how fast find_in_set would or if there are any other limitations